# $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{-x}\cosh(\alpha x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I compute this limit with $\alpha>0$.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x} \cosh(\alpha x)$$

For $\alpha=1$ it is simple, but if $\alpha \neq1$ it isn't simple.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is basically the same as $e^{-x} e^{\alpha x} = e^{(\alpha - 1) x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that $cosh(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x})$ by definition, we can take \begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}cosh(\alpha x) &= \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{-x}\frac{1}{2}(e^{\alpha x} + e^{-\alpha x}) \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{2}(e^{(\alpha-1) x} + e^{(-\alpha-1) x}) \\
\end{aligned}
Which converges to :

$0$ for $|\alpha|<1$

$\frac{1}{2}$ for $|\alpha|=1$

and will diverge otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we know $cosh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. So now we see $cosh(\alpha x)=\frac{e^{\alpha x}-e^{-\alpha x}}{2}$. Using this formula in the limit, we have:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}cosh(\alpha x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}\frac{1}{2}(e^{\alpha x}-e^{-\alpha x})=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\alpha x-x}-e^{-(\alpha x+x)}$$
From here one can deduce that the limit equals $\frac{1}{2}$ if $\alpha =1$, it equals $\infty$ if $\alpha\gt 1$ and it equals $0$ if $0\lt \alpha \lt 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just use
$\cosh(x)
=\frac12(e^x+e^{-x})
\approx \frac12 e^x
$.